# Is there any way to copy (only) C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\ through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I need to use PowerShell (with admin creds) to make a copy of (only) `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\`:

1. without interrupting the workstation.
2. with some capability built into Windows (and sysinternals is allowed).
3. reliably across versions at least back to Windows 7 SP1.
4. an entire drive cannot be copied, only the specific directory.

I'm now aware of:

- [disk2vhd (sysinternals)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd)
- robocopy
- [System state backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/dpm/back-up-system-state-and-bare-metal?view=sc-dpm-2019)
- `wbadmin start backup -include:C:\Windows\System32\config -backupTarget:E: -quiet`

as options for making a copy of `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\`, however, these methods do not, as far as I can see in the documentation, have a straight-forward option for copying a specific directory.

The reason for the requirement of using Windows or sysinternals is this is supposed to run on client systems with network owners who don't necessarily trust us. So my thinking is if it's based on systems built into Windows or sysinternals, and written in PowerShell, that's going to have the highest likelihood of being approved by a network admin (since they should understand exactly what the script is doing).

What I tried:

- copy doesn't work (file in use)
- robocopy doesn't work (errors on many of the files)
- disk2vhd doesn't (seem to) support single directory copying
- System state backup doesn't (seem to) support single directory copying
- `wbadmin start backup -include:C:\Windows\System32\config -backupTarget:E: -quiet` isn't reliable across a range of Windows versions, at least when tested on Windows 11 Pro: `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wbadmin start backup -include:C:\Windows\System32\config -backupTarget:E: -quiet wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool (C) Copyright Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.  Retrieving volume information... A partial backup of volumes is not supported on this version of Windows.`

Comment: Normally you would be able to access a file being used by another process using this method: `$fs = [System.IO.FileStream]::new('path/to/systemfile', [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)` however doesnt seem to work with system files

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I've spent all day looking for a solution to this. Never imagined it could be this hard to copy a file.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you but this might not be possible by normal means..

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Wow. That's surprising. I wonder if there's a good reason for this. I will be keeping that code in my back pocket for later, anyhow,. thanks.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It turns out this is possible, for this very specific instance. At least, the desired outcome is possible, under the desired requirements. Just not through through the means I imagined (by copying the files directly). `get-winevent` can pull all the data from these files. Then, `ConvertTo-Json` can export the data.

Comment: Good to know, I would recommend XML instead of Json for this particular case, remember `EventLogRecord` instances have a `ToXml()` method ;)